# How to call another FAKE build script from within a build script?

Tags: f#, f#-fake

I have a collection of repos under the same root directory. Each repo contains a build.fsx to compile & test etc.

I want to create one FAKE build.fsx in the root directory that can trigger the build.fsx scripts in the sibling repo directories.

I'm not worried about the loop, but how best to call another build.fsx from within the originating build.fsx?

I am sure `Shell.Exec("./packages/tools/FAKE.exe", "./otherdir/build.fsx")` would work, but is there a more seamless approach built into FAKE?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is built into FAKE, so if you want the 'sibling' build scripts to be used independently of the main script then your `Shell.Exec` approach is likely a very good one (and what I would use).  That said ...

A slight variation on that approach would be to load the sibling .fsx files and then compose their build targets in the 'parent' build script:

```
#load "Sibling.fsx" 

"LocalTarget" 
    ==> "SiblingTarget"
```

You will get errors if the target names conflict, and it could be confusing, so a naming convention would be smart (eg "`Build_Sibling_1`", "`Clean_Sibling_2`", etc).